# how to test my login page of admin contrller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I have controller:

```
def login
  if admin_logged_in?
    flash[:notice]="You are already logged in"
    redirect_to( "/admin/")
  else
    render(:layout => "admin")
  end
end
```

my RSpec test case

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "AdminController" do
before (:each) do
    @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
end

describe "GET 'login'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'login'
      response.should be_success
    end
end
end
```

when I am going execute my test case getting error:

```
 1) AdminController GET 'login' should be successful
     Failure/Error: get 'login'
     RuntimeError:
       @controller is nil: make sure you set it in your test's setup method.
     # ./spec/controllers/admin_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.18799 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/admin_controller_spec.rb:9
```

Comment: Check your normal login. and let me whether its working..?

Answer (score 0):

In your test, I would replace the describe block of `"AdminController"` to `AdminController`. Your test should now look like this...

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe AdminController do
before (:each) do
  @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
end

describe "GET 'login'" do
  it "should be successful" do
    get 'login'
    response.should be_success
  end
end
end
```

Explanation: Because you wrote AdminController in parenthesis, rspec was not able to tell which controller you were testing.